How to use two primary color in shadcn?
I have three admin panels in a Next.js app using Shadcn, and each panel has a unique primary color. Is there a way to change the Shadcn primary color for each panel independently?
I was considering creating a context for each panel to set the colors dynamically.

Why not extend the colors in the Tailwind config and just add a suffix to the word primary for each of the panels? Something like: primary-panel-one: [color here] and do the same for the rest of the panels.

I want to change the primary color for all Shadcn components. If i add the extended color in config file the components will have the default primary color.
